# Why programm (massif) will be true?

Tags: javascript

So,i know that: `null`, `" "`, `undefined,0, NaN` will return `false` and all other value in JS will be `true`, but why:

```js
console.log([] - 1)          // -1 (it`s mean that [] = 0 (value of false?)
console.log([] - [])         // 0 (wtf?),[] = 1?
if([]) console.log('true')   // true
console.log(null - 1)        // -1
if(null) console.log('true') // (false, no output)
```

Somebody, can you explain me what is going on?

Comment: they just get converted into their numerical representation (cast).

Comment: You are using `-`, which converts the arguments into numbers, which has nothing to do with truthiness of the value.

Comment: Why that WTF comment? If you already deduced in the first statement that `[]`'s numerical value is `0`, then why would `0 - 0 = 0` be surprising?

Comment: js can be pretty weird, especially when it comes to automatic conversions. Maybe this post (repo) can shed some light: https://github.com/denysdovhan/wtfjs#-is-equal-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-` operator coerces the operands to `Number`. `if (expression)` coerces the expression to `Boolean`.

So let's see what `[]` and `null` coerce to as `Number` and `Boolean`...

```js
console.log('  [] as Number: ', Number([]) );    //0
console.log('  [] as Boolean:', Boolean([]) );   //true
console.log('null as Number: ', Number(null) );  //0
console.log('null as Boolean:', Boolean(null) ); //false
```

With that information, you get some clarity as to how each expression of yours is logging the corresponding value.

```js
                               // Output |  Evaluated As
console.log([] - 1)            // -1     |  (0 - 1)
console.log([] - [])           // 0      |  (0 - 0)
if([]) console.log('true')     // true   |  ( if(true) )
console.log(null - 1)          // -1     |  (0 - 1)
if(null) console.log('true')   // (none) |  ( if(false) )
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an arithmetic expression. According to ECMAScript Language Specification, in arithmetic expression different types are converted as follows:

[image]

In expression the `array` (`[]`) is considered as `object` and converted to accordingly.

Full reference [**here**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3).

Comment: No, `null` is not an object. It has its own row in the table

Comment: Yes! I considered `typeof null`. Thanks :)